# MobSF (Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF) installation problems

Tags: python, django, git, docker, installation

I spent last days striving with MobSF (Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF) installation, which finally fails without reaching the target.
My work laptop is Windows 10 with i5-8250U  and 16G memory.

I tried it using

```
git clone https://github.com/MobSF/Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF.git
```

then running setup.bat
Meanwhile installing Python (Python 3.11.2), OpesnSSL (64 bit) and Visual studio.
The BAT file runs slowly ... unfortunately fails

```
[ERROR] Installation Failed!
```

throwing errors:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement yara-python-dex>=1.0.1 (from apkid==2.1.4->-r requirements.txt (line 24)) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for yara-python-dex>=1.0.1 (from apkid==2.1.4->-r requirements.txt (line 24))
```

and

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\ij\tools\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\manage.py", line 12, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
```

Trying to kludge it around:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
python -m pip install django
```

But it still does not work.

Another attempt was installation using

```
docker build -t mobsf .
```

But it finishes:

```
#9 [ 5/15] RUN ./install_java_wkhtmltopdf.sh
#9 sha256:dfd7a75b84c7012f1ce18ad20ea32f7e4921afdc40b5cc22287585713c5f8bd2
#9 0.688 /bin/sh: 1: ./install_java_wkhtmltopdf.sh: not found
#9 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c ./install_java_wkhtmltopdf.sh]: exit code: 127
------
 > [ 5/15] RUN ./install_java_wkhtmltopdf.sh:
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c ./install_java_wkhtmltopdf.sh]: exit code: 127
```

Google hardly shows anything about it.

**I will appreciate any hint to solve. May be there is another way to install MobSF**

Answer (score 0):

Install python 3.8 or 3.9 your issue will be solved

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).